# Xero callback url won't work without a forward slash

Tags: coldfusion, xero-api

When setting up an app in Xero Developer, it wont let you setup a callback URL with a forward slash eg `/callback.cfm`. It will only except `callback.cfm. So when it comes back, it goes to`https://dev.colossus.systemscallback.cfm`and not`https://dev.colossus.systems/callback.cfm`.

I have tried every perceivable combination, but the OAuth 1.0a Callback Domain in the app setup will not allow you to use a forward slash. Even the URL with a slash on the end won't work.

If I try this:

```
"CallbackBaseUrl" : "https://dev.colossus.systems/",
"CallbackPath" : "xero-callback.cfm"
```

or

```
"CallbackBaseUrl" : "https://dev.colossus.systems",
"CallbackPath" : "/xero-callback.cfm"
```

.. the callback URL is wrong.

```
"CallbackBaseUrl" : "https://dev.colossus.systems",
"CallbackPath" : "xero-callback.cfm"
```

This works, however it comes back as `https://dev.colossus.systemscallback.cfm`

```
json
"CallbackBaseUrl" : "https://dev.colossus.systems",
"CallbackPath" : "xero-callback.cfm"
```

I expect it to be able to take `/callback.cfm` in the API admin, but it won't take it.

Answer (score 1):

found the issue, the callback domain is the just the url and has nothing to do with the return address

Comment: Correct. For OAuth1 you only specify the domain, not the full url, when creating your app.